# How to convert string to POSIX in R when the string has abbreviated weekday and monthday

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert strings to POSIXlt format. The string are defined like:

`x <- "Mon Jul 13 14:28:42 2015"`

I used the following format specifications for date and time conversion:

`dateformat <- "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"`

- %a: Abbreviated weekday name in the current locale on this platform
- %b: Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform
- %d: Day of the month as decimal number (01–31)
- %H: Hours as decimal number (00–23)
- %M: Minute as decimal number (00–59)
- %S: Second as integer (00–61)
- %Y: Year with century

My locale settings are:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252; LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252; 
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252; LC_NUMERIC=C; LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

My session info is:

```
sessionInfo()  
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.5.0             dplyr_0.4.3                 rosetta_0.0.1               plyr_1.8.3                 
[5] scanEngineParser_0.0.1.9001

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] magrittr_1.5   R6_2.1.1       assertthat_0.1 parallel_3.2.2 DBI_0.3.1      tools_3.2.2    Rcpp_0.12.2    stringi_1.0-1 
 [9] stringr_1.0.0  XML_3.98-1.3
```

Everything seems ok, but I get NA results:

- strptime:
  `> strptime(x = x, format = dateformat)
  [1] NA`
- as.Date:
  `>as.Date(x = x, format = dateformat)
  [1] NA`
- Same with: as.POSIXlt , as.POSIXct , strftime, ...

I suposed that the problem was the weekday and mothday abbreviated, so I checked with:

`> format(Sys.time(), format = dateformat)
[1] "Tue Dec 29 18:38:56 2015"`

Even if I use the string generated with format it will return NA:

`> strptime(x = format(Sys.time(), format = dateformat), format = dateformat)
[1] NA`

Do you know what is happening?
How I can convert this string to POSIXlt?

Comment: Not particularly helpful perhaps, but when I run your example, it works fine for me, with the output of `strptime(x = x, format = dateformat)` being POSIXlt.

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior. What's your `sessionInfo()` output? Please edit it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted RStudio, but the problem persisted.
I restarted SO (Windows 10), and now it work as it should... the issue may be related with SO.

Lesson learned...